# How can I make a circle to move randomly in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to make this ball move randomly when I load the page, but only in movements of 15 by 15, for example, now that the ball is in (80,80) it can move randomly to (95,80), (80,95), (65,80) or (80,65), and it needs to keep moving every 15 px, but not so fast, it needs to stay there fore a moment and then move again

Honestly I don't know what to do, I've been stucked but haven't figure out how to do it, please help me but a simple way

```js
"use strict";
let ctx;


function setup() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    ball(80,80);
}

function ball(x,y) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // head
    ctx.fill();
}

function moveBall(){
  ball(x,y);
  
}

function moveRandom() {
 Math.floor(Math.random()*8)*30 + 15
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Run</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setup()">
    <h1>Run</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you calling "moveBall" from? Also your "moveRandom" function looks incomplete, its not using the generated random value anywhere

Comment: the "moveBall" I created it to have the random movement going

Comment: but its not being used

Comment: because it is the thing I don't know how to use, I don't know how to create the movement for the ball

Comment: You need a [timed function execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and a counter for timing the change to the direction of the ball. In the timed function, first check the counter, and if it's time to change the direction, reset the counter and call `moveRandom`. Return a random direction (ex. 0 - 360) from that function, calculate the new coordinates, draw the ball, increase the counter, and call the timed function again. You also need to recalculate the direction when the ball is going out of the borders when calculating the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not very clear, what kind of desired movement you want, however the below snippet should give basic idea, you can refine it further to get the desired output:

```js
"use strict";
let ctx, canvas;


function setup() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
    ball(80,80);
}

function ball(x,y) {
  //first clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.save();
  //ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // head
    ctx.fill();
}

function moveBall(){
  var x = moveRandom();
  var y = moveRandom();
  console.log("moving to: ", x,y);
  ball(x, y);
  
}

function moveRandom() {
 //canvas width and height is same in your case, so multiplied by one to get both x and y. This will give x, y values within canvas.
 return Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Run</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setup()" onclick="moveBall()">
    <h1>Run</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

The movement is `onclick` of body, but can be changed by simply calling your `moveBall` function from desired event e.g. `mousemove`, canvas `onclick` etc. Or if you want time based movement, use `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` with `setTimeout` to call `moveBall`.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Vector class

Let us start by creating a Vector class. It will make things easier. We are, of course working in 2D, thus our vectors are going to be 2D. So We create a constructor that takes `x` and `y`:

```
    class Vector {
        constructor(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

These vectors aren't really vectors unless we have some operations. Namely addition and scalar product. So let us add them:

```
        add(other) {
            return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
        }
```

As you can see, addition is simply adding the vectors member-wise.

For the calar product, we simply multiply the members by a factor:

```
        scaled(factor) {
            return new Vector(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
        }
```

To make a subtraction, we could do `a.add(b.sacled(-1))`, but it is convenient to have a difference method:

```
        diff(other) {
            return new Vector(this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y);
        }
```

And we want a "norm" or length of the vector, which is just Pythagoras':

```
        length() {
            return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
        }
```

---

### Game loop

Now, that we have our Vector class, let us talk about the game cycle. *What? you say this is not a game? Well, shush, we are writing it like one.*

In the web we want to use `requestAnimationFrame` for your game cycle. We will call it one during initialization (`setup`), and we will have it call itself. We will use `performace.now()` to pass the time:

```
    function tick(newTime){
        // ...
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

    function setup() {
        // ...
        time = performance.now();
        tick(time);
    }
```

We need to know how much time elapsed since the last frame. So declare `time` in the outer scope, to keep track of the last time, and we compute `delta` like this:

```
    function tick(newTime){
        let delta = (newTime - time) / 1000.0;
        time = newTime;
        
        // ...

        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
```

Note that I divide by `1000.0`, this is so I get the value in seconds not milliseconds.

The game cycle will take input (none, in this case), update the state (move the ball), and output (draw to the canvas).

---

**Update state**

So, we need a state. Let us represent the position of the ball with a vector. Similarly the position were it is going, the velocity, speed, etc...

In fact we will have:

```
    let position = new Vector(80, 80); // Pixels
    let target = new Vector(80, 80); // Pixels
    let direction = new Vector(0, 0); // Pixels
    let speed = 15.0; // Pixels per second
    let step = 15.0; // Pixels
```

Now, the distance the ball would have moved in `delta` seconds is:

```
        let distanceToCover = delta * speed;
```

And we can update the position like this:

```
        position = position.add(direction.scaled(distanceToCover));
```

Here we are assuming that `direction` is a unit vector. Scaling it by `distanceToCover` gives us the offset the ball would have moved in `delta` seconds. We add that to the current position to get the updated position.

But what direction does the ball move? Well, once the ball reached its target, we pick a direction at random… Ah, we need to check if we reached the target!

```
        if (position.diff(target).length() < distanceToCover) {
            // ...
        }
```

There we compute the distance from the position to the target, and see if it is less than the distance the ball would cover. You can think of this as checking if we are about to overshoot the target.

Please note that we cannot rely on the position matching the target perfectly. On one hand, in practice the ball is changing position discretely (except it does so each frame), so it might not hit the target. On the other, it would not anyway because floating point errors.

Ok, now we need a direction at random. That is easy, we use `Math.random()`:

```
            let angle = (Math.random() * Math.PI * 2.0) - Math.PI;
            direction = new Vector(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle));
```

There we pick an angle in the range from -PI to PI radians, and we create a unit vector from it using trigonometry.

We also need to update the target position:

```
            target = position.add(direction.scaled(step));
```

The target position is the current position plus the direction we computed, scaled by the step.

---

I found a bug. Good old tunneling. So I'll measure distance traveled instead of distance to target. So I need the start position instead of the target.

This is the fixed code:

```
        if (position.diff(start).length() + distanceToCover > step) {
            // ...
            start = position;
        }
```

Oh, one more thing, that conditional would be false if I initialize `start` to the same value than `position`, and then it never picks another `start`. Thus, `start` must be initialized to be away from `position`.

I know there are other thing to improve for "correctness". In particular resetting the position to the computed target, and taking into account by how much we overshot to remove time from the motion.

However, remember the first law of computer graphics: If it looks right, it is right -Flecher Dunn & Ian Parberry

---

**Output**

Simple, clear the canvas, draw the ball:

```
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall(position);
```

---

### CODE

This is working code:

```js
"use strict";

class Vector {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    add(other) {
        return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }

    diff(other) {
        return new Vector(this.x - other.x, this.y - other.y);
    }

    scaled(factor) {
        return new Vector(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
    }

    length() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }
}

let ctx;
let canvas;
let time;
let position = new Vector(80, 80); // Pixels
let start = new Vector(Infinity, Infinity); // Pixels
let direction = new Vector(0, 0); // Pixels
let speed = 15.0; // Pixels per second
let step = 15.0; // Pixels

function tick(newTime){
    let delta = (newTime - time) / 1000.0;
    time = newTime;
    
    let distanceToCover = delta * speed;
    if (position.diff(start).length() + distanceToCover > step) {
        let angle = (Math.random() * Math.PI * 2.0) - Math.PI;
        direction = new Vector(Math.cos(angle), Math.sin(angle));
        start = position;
    }
    
    position = position.add(direction.scaled(distanceToCover));

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall(position);
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function setup() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    time = performance.now();
    tick(time);
}

function drawBall(position) {
    ctx.save();
    {
        ctx.translate(position.x, position.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI); // head
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Run</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="setup()">
    <h1>Run</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="400" width="400" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```